# How to build JavaFX styleable objects properly, that can be GC

Tags: javafx, memory-leaks

I decided to refactor my application because of hugh memory leaks in the old version.  For visualization objects, I decide to not more using fxml, but Styleable interface.

So I created a class Sim Photo like this :

```
 public class SimPhoto extends Control {

    private static final String DEFAULT_CLASS_NAME = "sim-photo";
    private static final Double DEFAULT_STROKE_WIDTH = 0.0;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private static String DEFAULT_PHOTO = "";

    private StyleableStringProperty imgPath;
    private StyleableIntegerProperty arcHeight;
    private StyleableIntegerProperty arcWidth;
    private DoubleProperty strokeWidth;
    private ObjectProperty<Paint> stroke;
    private ObjectProperty<Paint> fill;

        public SimPhoto() {
        initialize();
    }

    public SimPhoto(@NamedArg("imgPath") String imgPath) {
        this();
        this.imgPathProperty().set(imgPath);

    }

    //Example of init properties
     public final StyleableIntegerProperty arcHeightProperty() {
        if (arcHeight == null) {
            arcHeight = new SimpleStyleableIntegerProperty(
                    StyleableProperties.ARC_WIDTH,
                    SimPhoto.this,
                    "arcWidth",
                    0
            );
        }
        return arcHeight;
    }

    public final StringProperty imgPathProperty() {
        if(imgPath == null) {
           imgPath =  new SimpleStyleableStringProperty(
                    StyleableProperties.IMG_PATH,
                    SimPhoto.this,
                    "imgPath",
                    "");
        }
        return imgPath;
    }
   (...)
 }
```

In my skin class, I use binding of properties from Control Class

```
public class SimPhotoSkin extends SkinBase<SimPhoto> {

    @Getter
    private Rectangle photoFond = new Rectangle();
    private Rectangle photoView = new Rectangle();

    private boolean invalidate = false;

    private InvalidationListener invalidListener = this::invalidated;
    private ChangeListener<String> pathListener = this::pathChanged;


    public SimPhotoSkin(SimPhoto control) {
        super(control);
        initVisualization();
        initListeners();
    }

    private void initVisualization() {
        getChildren().addAll(photoFond, photoView);
        if (getSkinnable().imgPathProperty() != null) {
            setNewFond(getSkinnable().getImgPath());
        }
    }

    private void initListeners() {
        photoFond.widthProperty().bind(getSkinnable().widthProperty().subtract(5));
        photoFond.heightProperty().bind(getSkinnable().heightProperty().subtract(5));
        photoView.widthProperty().bind(photoFond.widthProperty().subtract(photoFond.strokeWidthProperty()));
        photoView.heightProperty().bind(photoFond.heightProperty().subtract(photoFond.strokeWidthProperty()));

        photoView.arcWidthProperty().bind(getSkinnable().arcWidthProperty());
        photoView.arcHeightProperty().bind(getSkinnable().arcHeightProperty());
        photoFond.arcWidthProperty().bind(getSkinnable().arcWidthProperty());
        photoFond.arcHeightProperty().bind(getSkinnable().arcHeightProperty());

        photoFond.fillProperty().bind(getSkinnable().fillProperty());
        photoFond.strokeProperty().bind(getSkinnable().strokeProperty());
        photoFond.strokeWidthProperty().bind(getSkinnable().strokeWidthProperty());
        getSkinnable().imgPathProperty().addListener(pathListener);
    }

    private void pathChanged(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
       (...)
    }

    private void setNewFond(String path) {
        (...)
    }
    private void invalidated(Observable observable) {
        invalidate = true;
    }
}
```

I know that object cannot been GC while exist a reference to it. So I have a big problem, because event these objects are no more used, thay cannot be GC , and in my application ,when I need creating more than 300 objects at time is a big problem.

I tried to create method clean(), that will be unbind all bidnings and listeners, but it's not realy helpful. Problem still persist.

I'm thinking about any workaround like a Manager, that will store all objects in queue and while calling will return one objects disponibles or create new one.

But this is the last possibility, if I dont find any solution for my problem, and I would like avoid this.

Comment: The `Skin` interface has a `dispose()` method you can override. It gets called if the `Skin` of a `Control`, or more generally `Skinnable`, gets changed. Otherwise, if your `Control` is no longer strongly referenced, then your `Skin` is most likely no longer strongly referenced and everything is GC'd. And the standard library implements `Property.bind` using [_weak_ listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/beans/WeakListener.html). You mention memory leaks, have you verified where these leaks are taking place?

Comment: Yes.. wen I create 1k objects in Hbox.. and after removing from, there are never  GC.

Comment: Another thing to check is if the garbage collector is actually running. I believe, at least on some implementations, the GC won't necessarily run if the JVM can allocate more memory first. If you are simply adding `Node`s to an `HBox` then removing them later they should be eligible for GC. (I'm sorry I'm not answering your question but I don't have a good answer so I'm just checking to make sure that you're sure there's actually a memory leak)

Comment: I create a workoaround.. because I cannot force to gc my objects anyway... I've created PanelManager for my project, with ObservableList as registry of objects, and flag isFree in objects.  So when I would like to initialize new object i call manager, who find first free object and return it, or create new one.